# Difference between 2 timestamps

Tags: abap

I have a program in ABAP where they use the type 'timestampl' in a variable, so they can get the time of certain events. They use it because they need the milliseconds.

I now have the mission of getting the difference between 2 of these variables, and I can't seem to find a function module or another solution.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: subtracts it ? what is the issue ? :-)

Comment: Well, I´m not sure if substracting directly is the way to go. Does that consider different days depending on the month and things like that?

Answer (score 5):

Use the method [**`CL_ABAP_TSTMP=>SUBTRACT`**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_tstmp.htm), by passing two timestamps which must be of the type `TIMESTAMPL` so that to contain milliseconds, and the difference between the 2 timestamps will be returned in number of seconds, including the milliseconds.

Example:

```
DATA: lv_tstmp1 TYPE timestampl,
      lv_tstmp2 TYPE timestampl,
      lv_diff   TYPE tzntstmpl.

lv_tstmp1 = '20190704000010.999'. " July 4th, 00:00:10 and 999 ms
lv_tstmp2 = '20190703235950.001'. " July 3rd, 23:59:50 and 001 ms

CALL METHOD cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract
    EXPORTING
      tstmp1 = lv_tstmp1
      tstmp2 = lv_tstmp2
    RECEIVING
      r_secs = lv_diff.

ASSERT lv_diff = '20.998'. " expectation verified or run time error
```

Answer (score 1):

A Google search turns up this recommendation: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/840ad679-0601-0010-cd8e-9989fd650822#q-8: use the class CL_ABAP_TSTMP.  You can also see an example of how to use the class in this thread:  http://scn.sap.com/thread/85476.

```
 cl_abap_tstmp=>systemtstmp_syst2utc(
    exporting
      syst_date = <wa_joblist>-strtdate
      syst_time = <wa_joblist>-strttime
    importing
      utc_tstmp = start_stamp ).

  cl_abap_tstmp=>systemtstmp_syst2utc(
    exporting
      syst_date = sy-datum
      syst_time = sy-uzeit
    importing
      utc_tstmp = now_stamp ).

  seconds = cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract(
      tstmp1 = now_stamp
      tstmp2 = start_stamp ).
```

Comment: This actually does not answer the question, which requires the delta in milliseconds..

Comment: The method `SUBTRACT` may accept timestamps with milliseconds, which would answer the question, but the example first uses methods which always return timestamps **without** milliseconds, so it ruins the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use the FM ***'CCU_TIMESTAMP_DIFFERENCE'***

After Checking which timestamp is greater call the FM.

```
IF TIMESTAMP_2 > TIMESTAMP_1.

 CALL FUNCTION 'CCU_TIMESTAMP_DIFFERENCE'
   EXPORTING
      TIMESTAMP1 = TIMESTAMP_2
      TIMESTAMP2 = TIMESTAMP_1 
   IMPORTING 
      DIFFERENCE = TIMESTAMP_DIFFERENCE.
EndIf.
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing proposals ignore the milliseconds. Here's a solution for modern ABAP AS that also considers msecs:

```
r_secs = CONV #( cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract(
  tstmp1 = CONV timestamp( i_ts1 )
  tstmp2 = CONV timestamp( i_ts1 )
) ).
r_secs = r_secs + ( frac( i_ts1 ) - frac( i_ts2 ) ).
```

i_ts1 and i_ts2 are two timestamps, r_secs (type f) is the result.

Here's a small tester:

```
REPORT ztest_timestampl_dif.

CLASS lcl_timestampl DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      test,
      dif
        IMPORTING
                  i_ts1         TYPE timestampl
                  i_ts2         TYPE timestampl
        RETURNING VALUE(r_secs) TYPE f.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_timestampl=>test( ).

CLASS lcl_timestampl IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD test.
    DATA:
      l_ts1   TYPE timestampl,
      l_ts2   TYPE timestampl,
      l_msecs TYPE f.

    GET TIME STAMP FIELD l_ts1.
    WAIT UP TO '0.378' SECONDS.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD l_ts2.

    l_msecs = dif( i_ts1 = l_ts1  i_ts2 = l_ts2 ).

    cl_demo_output=>display( l_msecs ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD dif.
    r_secs = CONV #( cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract(
      tstmp1 = CONV timestamp( i_ts1 )
      tstmp2 = CONV timestamp( i_ts1 )
    ) ).
    r_secs = r_secs + ( frac( i_ts1 ) - frac( i_ts2 ) ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Consider to add handling for overflows, if you are using it productive.